# checkbox won't enable/disable until control loses focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox

I’m working on an ASP.net page that displays a datagrid with a checkbox and a dropdownlist in each row. To continue on to the next step, each row must either have a check or an option selected, but never both.

I am attempting to disable the dropdownlist if the checkbox is checked, and to disable the checkbox if any option except “Select a Reason” is selected. I’m trying to do everything client side, using jquery 1.4 (I know its old, but that’s the UI leads decision).

**My code works fine in Chrome and IE8, but when I use Firefox 16 the checkbox does not disable upon selection change, until the user clicks outside the grid. Then the box disables. I want to get rid of the extra click.**

Here is the grid markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvApps" runat="server" CssClass="sGrid"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            EmptyDataText="No Data" PageSize="3" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
        <itemtemplate> 
            <asp:checkbox id = "gvCheckbox" runat="server"  onclick="RowCheckChanged(this)" />
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField datafield="FiscalYear" HeaderText="Year"    />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
            <itemtemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList id = "ddlReason"  Viewstate="true" DataSource="<%# ReasonsList %>"  runat="server" />
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <emptydatatemplate>
        <p class="norecords">There are currently no Records </p>
    </emptydatatemplate> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my OnReady:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").change(function () {
            $(IndexChanged(this));
        });
    })
</script>
```

Here are the IndexChanged and RowCheckChanged functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function RowCheckChanged(objRef) {
    var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (objRef.checked) {
        $(row).find("select").attr("selectedIndex", 0);
        $(row).find("select")[0].disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        $(row).find("select")[0].disabled = false;
    }
}


function IndexChanged(objRef) {
    //toggle  chkb enabled-ness
    var row = objRef.parentNode.parentNode;

    if ($(row).find("select option:selected").text() == "Select a Reason") {
        //both objects should be enabled
        $(row).find(":checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
     } else {
        //a selection has been made, disable checkbox.
        $(row).find(":checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
</script>
```

Any Ideas?

Edit: here is the markup generated by the grid client side (per firebug):

```
<select id="MainContent_wiz_IntraAppYears1_gvApps_ddlReason_0" viewstate="true" name="ctl00$MainContent$wiz$IntraAppYears1$gvApps$ctl02$ddlReason" disabled="">
    <option value="Select a Reason" selected="selected">Select a Reason</option>
    <option value="Tax Exempt">Tax Exempt</option>
    <option value="Out of Business">Out of Business</option>
    <option value="Worked under Another Authority">Worked under Another Authority</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed me to the .click event for FF and IE, and it seems to be working great. I no longer need the dropdown list to lose focus before the event fires. it seems chrome doesn't like .click, so I have to link the event conditionally.

Here is my new OnReady:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
        $("select").change(function () {
            $(IndexChanged(this));
        });
    } else {
        $("select").click(function () {
            $(IndexChanged(this));
        });
    }
```

Thanks to  charlietfl for the help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
 $(row).find(":checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and

```
$(row).find(":checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Syntax is not exactly the same as `prop()` method available in newer versions of jQuery and has worked for me in older versions of FF, IE 6-8 etc

**DEMO Using jQuery 1.4:** http://jsbin.com/otuyez/1/edit

Also following doesn't need to be wrapped in `$()` as it is strictly a function call

```
$(IndexChanged(this));
```

Can simply call the function as handler for `select` change:

```
 $(function () {
    $("select").change(IndexChanged);
})
```

Some other tweaks that may assist

```
$(row).find("select").attr("selectedIndex", 0);
```

Could be written as

```
$(row).find("select").val('')
```

Comment: no dice I'm afraid. I've confirmed using firebug that the change event isn't firing until after the user makes their selection and then clicks somewhere else. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: seems really odd...is there any markup irreglarity ... a missing quote in options for example?

Comment: I've added the client rendered markup for the select element. everything looks alright, but let me know. I'll look at your other comments as well. Thanks!

Comment: trying to replicate with select change and it seems to work fine in FF   could be some sort of css issue also. **demo** http://jsbin.com/otuyez/2/edit

Comment: that jsbin sight is very neat. thanks for putting that together and showing it to me. most appreciated.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is even easier... you can include most major libraries like jQuery by checking a box